# How can I scan from a txt file in C

Tags: c

I want to scan the number 28 and 210 from this txt file:

```
k 8

p edge 28 210

e 4 3

e 5 2

e 6 1

e 7 3
```

and i have this code:

```
 struct VyE
 {
   int vertices;
   int enlaces;
 };

struct VyE obtenerNumVerticesYenlaces(char* ruta){

    // Abre el archivo de texto en modo de lectura
  FILE* fp = fopen(ruta, "r");
  struct VyE datos; 
  if (fp == NULL) {
      // Si ha habido un error al abrir el archivo, muestra un mensaje de error y finaliza el programa
      printf("Error al abrir el archivo\n");
      datos.enlaces=0;
      datos.vertices=0;
      return datos;
  }
  // Lee los valores 28 y 210 del archivo
  fscanf(fp, "p edge %d %d", &datos.vertices, &datos.enlaces);
  fclose(fp);
  return datos;

}
```

but when i debug it i get bigger values and not what i want.

How can i get these values?

Comment: If `sscanf` on the string returns `4` items converted, (and presumably the first two items match your requirement) you are done. Or like the code, `if(sscanf(buffer, "p edge %d %d", &datos.vertices, &datos.enlaces) == 2)`

Comment: you need to skip over the first two lines of the file (or maybe 1, its not clear if there are blank lines in the file)